# A JS CLI Table with arrow keys functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I want to create a CLI with a table, and when you press the arrow up/down key, the next/previous row will be highlighted. I have no idea how to do that, is there any library that does that?

Comment: Please do your own research first - use the search feature on npmjs.com, put in some effort. If you sort by popularity, you should get some good matches for e.g. "terminal interface" as a search keyword.

Comment: Robert Kawecki, I did, I could not find. Thats why I came here